# Closure Compiler not Compiling ES6 library

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am in the process of writing a rather large JavaScript library using the Closure Compiler, but I made a smaller mock up to use as an example of this issue:

*src/main.js*:

```
export function main(str) {
    console.log("From main: " + str);
}
```

Command:

```
google-closure-compiler --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --language_in ECMASCRIPT6 --language_out ECMASCRIPT6 --js_module_root src/ --module_resolution node --js src/main.js --js_output_file build/main.min.js
```

Expected Result (roughly):

```
export function main(str){console.log("From main: "+str)}
```

Actual Result:

```
'use strict';
```

Long story short, I've been struggling for hours, and I can't figure out how to get Closure Compiler to respect ES6 "export" statements. I've tried googling many times, but I can only get results for *"goog.modules"*, which isn't what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure Compiler does not currently support modules as output (in any format).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that with a few simple externs hacks, it's quite simple to convince Closure to produce AMD modules, or even CommonJS modules if you're dedicated enough, but I've yet to find a work around for ES6 modules. Perhaps I can write a grunt script to manipulate Closure's output, but that'll require making extensive modifications to my build system.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't out-of-the-box possible with the Closure Compiler but you can always parse and transform its output.

This answer assumes that:

- your library doesn't ship with third-party dependencies.
- and you're ok with distributing the library as a single compiled file.

Here we go…

This is a math library; one file per function:

```
// add.js
export default function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

```
// inc.js
import add from './add.js';

export default function inc(a) {
  return add(a, 1);
}
```

```
// sum.js
import add from './add.js';

export default function sum(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(add, 0);
}
```

We want to ship this library into a single compiled file:

```
// lib.js
import add from './add.js';
import inc from './inc.js';
import sum from './sum.js';

globalThis['my/namespace'] = {};
globalThis['my/namespace']['add'] = add;
globalThis['my/namespace']['inc'] = inc;
globalThis['my/namespace']['sum'] = sum;
```

---

**Why `globaThis`?**

For the readers who don't know, the Closure Compiler can remove stuff quite aggressively. For example a function that isn't called anywhere in your code is completely eliminated from the compiled output.

However the Closure Compiler recognises a few global objects as a mean to distribute code. So we can attach things to them. (If you only intended to target browsers you could swap it for  the `window` object.)

**Why `['foo']` and not `.foo`?**

Property names expressed that way don't get mangled by the Closure Compiler and therefore makes externs files unnecessary.

---

Let's compile our library:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
closure-compiler \
    --language_in ECMASCRIPT_NEXT \
    --language_out ECMASCRIPT_NEXT \
    --module_resolution NODE \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED \
    --js add.js inc.js sum.js lib.js \
    --entry_point lib.js \
    --js_output_file out.js
```

Here's the (prettified) output:

```
function b(a, c) {
  return a + c
}
globalThis["my/namespace"] = {}
globalThis["my/namespace"].add = b
globalThis["my/namespace"].inc = function (a) {
  return a + 1
}
globalThis["my/namespace"].sum = function (a) {
  return a.reduce(b, 0)
}
```

Now is the time to parse and transform the output.

We need to locate this statement: `globalThis["my/namespace"] = {}`

1. Everything before, we keep.
2. Everything after, we transform into `export` statements.
3. The statement itself is dropped.

Here's a screenshot of [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/):

[image]

The output is quite sequential so we don't need a full-blown AST traversal machinery:

```
import {readFileSync} from 'node:fs';
import {Parser} from 'acorn';
import {generate} from 'astring';

const parser_options = {sourceType: 'module', ecmaVersion: 'latest'};
const source = readFileSync('out.js');
const ast = Parser.parse(source, parser_options);

// Position of `globalThis['my/namespace'] = {}` in the AST
const limit = ast.body.findIndex(node => {
  return node.type == 'ExpressionStatement' &&
         node.expression.left.property.value === 'my/namespace';
}); 

ast.body = [
  // All the AST nodes **before** `globalThis['my/namespace'] = {}`.
  // These we keep.
  ...ast.body.slice(0, limit),

  // All the AST nodes **after** `globalThis['my/namespace'] = {}`.
  // These we transform:
  ...ast.body.slice(limit + 1).map(node => {
    const key = node.expression.left.property.name;
    const val = generate(node.expression.right);
    return Parser.parse(`export const ${key} = ${val};`, parser_options);
  })
];

console.log(generate(ast));
```

Notes:

1. `acorn` turns code into an AST.
2. `astring` turns AST into code.

And here's the final output:

```
function b(a, c) {
  return a + c;
}
;
export const add = b;

export const inc = function (a) {
  return a + 1;
};

export const sum = function (a) {
  return a.reduce(b, 0);
};
```

---

And now let's pause for a moment and marvel at how clever the Closure Compiler is. Look at how it has refactored the `inc` function ;)

I don't know what the guys at Google would make of that but it does seems to work well enough for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> If you compile just the function below with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS,
>   Closure Compiler produces empty output:
>
> function displayNoteTitle(note) {   alert(note['myTitle']); }
>
> Because the function is never called in the JavaScript that you pass
>   to the compiler, Closure Compiler assumes that this code is not
>   needed!

[**Ref**](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?csw=1#export)

You should add a part which calls your function

```
function displayNoteTitle(note) {
  alert(note['myTitle']);
}
displayNoteTitle({'myTitle': 'Flowers'});
```

Or you can add it to window object

```
function displayNoteTitle(note) {
  alert(note['myTitle']);
}
// Store the function in a global property referenced by a string:
window['displayNoteTitle'] = displayNoteTitle;
```

[Live example](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Aexport%2520function%2520main(str)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(%2522From%2520main%253A%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520str)%253B%250A%257D%250A%250Awindow%255B'main'%255D%2520%253D%2520main%253B)

Comment: While this is a good idea 1) it's a library, so it only exports functions & classes, but never calls them itself, and 2) it's not explicitly intended for browsers, so the "window" option isn't applicable. Even so, thank you so much for responding so promptly!

Comment: @ChefCyanide Solution: Export the Symbols You Want to Keep

***What if you want to compress only a set of function definitions to create a small, reusable library?*** How do you prevent Closure Compiler from removing all the functions?

The best solution in this case is to export your functions, as the following example illustrates: `function displayNoteTitle(note) {
  alert(note['myTitle']);
}
// Store the function in a global property referenced by a string:
window['displayNoteTitle'] = displayNoteTitle;` this is what their doc suggests

Comment: Yes, I also read their documentation, but as I explained in my comment, that will not work for my use case.

Comment: @ChefCyanide notice highlighted lines, in doc itself they are talking about set of function definition and reusable library.

Comment: Such an approach will not work in an environment like Node where "window" does not exist. As I am trying to support both the browser and Node, that approach will not work for me.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, while this is likely the reason my function is removed, the code should not be considered unused because it is already reachable externally through the "export" statement. Perhaps this merits filing an issue on the Closure Compiler's GitHub...